# Multiple div on one page change color in css

Tags: html, css

I have a multiple div and I want to change div border color but I don't know how many div on this page, How to change all div border color. I have past is code IS THIS RIGHT OR NOT.

```css
div {
  height: 5%;
  width: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="B1">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div> <br />
<div class="B2">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B3">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B4">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B5">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B6">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B7">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />

<div class="B8">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div><br />
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. i have added your code into a snippet and as you can see it is working fine, please check your own code next time

Comment: Yes ,i see its working when i put div and add border color, but it is not possible all div we use for border color we can we div for many things. So when will i do?

Comment: `div` in css targets all divs regardless of how many you have.

Comment: like i don't want to change last div color so what will I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED AGAIN TO REFLECT NEW QUESTIONS:

as you can see [@this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8Lnapnx/) you can target all but the last one div with css ... by using `div:not(:last-child) { border-color: red; }`

there are many css selectors and their uses, for example, you can read some pretty neat solutions here [@css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Comment: sir my question is simple: I have a page and on this page, i have multiple border-color so i want to change all border color in CSS , but i don't know how many classes are there. How to do.

Comment: Are looking for a JavaScript function to count all the the Classes rendered in the DOM? Or is it really that simple that you want put in your css at the end this line: div { border-color: red !important } which will override all the divs and their borders?

Comment: ok, you are asking me as it pasted in above if I use div for another purpose then div color also changes then what will I do.

Comment: I do not really understand to what you just wrote. So please, do you or do you not want just the css selector or you need some javascript counter of elements with particular classes?